# Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java/bin/java"

Tags: macos, mac, java

I am having an issue with Java in my Mac (OS X 10.7.3). Previously I installed it and it was working fine. After some changes in the .bash_profile and .profile file in the course of time, I am having an error like `Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java/bin/java"` whenever I try to run "javac" or "java" in my terminal.

`echo $PATH` gives an output like:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/sabya/Documents/Play_Framework/play-2.0:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

My .bash_profile looks like:

```
alias start_mysql="/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start"
alias stop_mysql="/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

Its bugging me for several days and reinstalling Java did not help. I'm a newbie in Mac and need help to sort out this issue. I Googled before posting this question but did not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably can just remove the definition of JAVA_HOME from `.bash_profile` and restart the shell. If you really need to set the variable, use

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java_home)
```

to define it dynamically depending on the installed JDK version or

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
```

to use the default place (which is symlinked to the above path).

Comment: Another trick worked . I just edited the .bash_profile and exported the JAVA_HOME as export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home . It solved the problem .

Comment: Indeed :-) It's a symbolic link leading (after some more redirections) to the same place. I've extended the answer accordingly.

Comment: Frequently you do not even need JAVA_HOME